# java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid

Tags: java, security, encryption, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I'm trying to read a   `X509 certificate`

```
FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("suresh.pfx");
CertificateFactory cf =   CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(fr);
```

And run in to the exception

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.nextenders.certificategeenrator.CertificateGenerator.testGenerateSignCertWithKeyStore(CertificateGenerator.java:102)
    at com.nextenders.certificategeenrator.CertificateGenerator.main(CertificateGenerator.java:65)
```

Found something related to it from [Oracle  forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1539590?tstart=1495) with no solution.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 16):

PFX isn't a certificate but a keystore in itself.

To get the certificate you have to load the pfx into a keystore and then get the certificate:

```java
InputStream certIs=new FileInputStream("suresh.pfx");
KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(certIs.getInputStream(),"password".toCharArray());
Certificate cert=ks.getCertificate("alias");
```

Regards