# How to get Certificate for encrypting mail into Java without private key?

Tags: java, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I want to send an encrypted mail in java. [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) (Release 1.6.4) seems to be popular to do so. In their example "CreateLargeEncryptedMail.java" you find:

```
/**
 * a simple example that creates a single encrypted mail message.
 * <p>
 * The key store can be created using the class in
 * org.bouncycastle.jce.examples.PKCS12Example - the program expects only one
 * key to be present in the key file.
 * <p>
 * Note: while this means that both the private key is available to
 * the program, the private key is retrieved from the keystore only for
 * the purposes of locating the corresponding public key, in normal circumstances
 * you would only be doing this with a certificate available.
 */
public class CreateLargeEncryptedMail
{
    public static void main(
        String args[])
        throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length != 3)
        {
            System.err.println("usage: CreateLargeEncryptedMail pkcs12Keystore password inputFile");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //
        // Open the key store
        //
        KeyStore    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        String      keyAlias = ExampleUtils.findKeyAlias(ks, args[0], args[1].toCharArray());

        Certificate[]   chain = ks.getCertificateChain(keyAlias);
```

But ks.getCertificateChain() does not work without the private key and usually I do not have the private key of a recipient.
In my tries it returned null. From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getCertificateChain(java.lang.String))

> Returns the certificate chain associated with the given alias. The certificate chain must have been associated with the alias by a call to setKeyEntry, or by a call to setEntry with a PrivateKeyEntry.

But I do not have the private key.

An other way would be to use `CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");` [is there a way to decrypt smime public key data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465375/is-there-a-way-to-decrypt-s-mime-public-key-data).

But I only come to 
`java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid`

Found [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794117/java-security-cert-certificateparsingexception-signed-fields-invalid) to that exception, but the solution uses `KeyStore.getCertificate()` again.

**I have**: A certificat suitable for SMIME in Windows trust store. The certificat works in outlook. I can export the certificat to a file.

**I want**: A java object of type Certificate (`X509Certificate`) working for SMIME with BounceCastle.

So what kind of file do I have to create with which tool and what to do in Java to get this X509Certificate initialized? Do I need the single certificat or a chain in that file? The certificat is self signed.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how encryption works in general. You encrypt something with your private key and provide your public key to anyone who wants to verify that the message was encrypted by you. You will never have clients private keys, as private keys MUST never be shared.

Comment: @leopal: I want only the recipient to be able to read my mail. So it must be the recipients private key which is neccessary for decryption. And I use the recipients public key to encrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BouncyCastle not only supports SMIME encryption but also contains a CertificateFactory which can load a p7b-file I exported from Windows certmgr. For export I chose without private key and with key-chain. That file worked for me using:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.x509.CertificateFactory;
...

    /**
     * Reads the Certificate from the file with filename.
     * Works for p7b-files.
     * @param filename the name and path of a key-file.
     * @return a Certificate
     */
    public static Certificate getCertificate(String filename) {
        Certificate cert = null;
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            CertificateFactory fact = new CertificateFactory();
            cert = fact.engineGenerateCertificate(is);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cert;
    }
```